# IE8 Script Error using this simple jQuery declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, function, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting the following **error** when I use this piece of script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('form').validVal(); // line 37
        });
    </script>
```

**Error:**

*"Object doesn't support this property or method" - Line 37, Char 4*

Can anyone explain how I fix this?

Is this a common error with IE/IE8?

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: You sure you don't get this error in other browsers, IE in debug mode shows such errors, maybe you run those others without error reporting...

Comment: Have you included the `validVal` script on the page?

Comment: Hi ipr101, yep I've added it on Line 13. Do you want me to post any of that script? It can be found here: http://validval.frebsite.nl/usage.php

Comment: Be sure that the link is valid (open page source and follow the link if the source viewer allows you for that)

Comment: Try giving the form an ID and select it using its ID: $('form#myForm').validVal();

Comment: False alarm people. My bad. I loaded a 2nd version of jQuery for an element further down the page. I have since removed this and all is glorious. My apologies for wasting your time here. Lesson learned. Thanks for the feedback and comments however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can use `validVal` method, you need to make sure to include the `validVal` plugin:

```
<script src="jquery.validVal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Second, check the selector - the way it is now it will apply this to *every* `form` element on the page.  You probably want to add something like `id="myForm"` to your `form element` and then use

```
$('#myForm').validVal();
```

Comment: False alarm people. My bad. I loaded a 2nd version of jQuery for an element further down the page. I have since removed this and all is glorious. My apologies for wasting your time here. Lesson learned. Thanks for the feedback and comments however.